# How to use KMP failure function to determine minimum length repeated substring?

Tags: algorithm, pattern-matching, knuth-morris-pratt

I want to solve [UVA 10298 -"Power Strings"](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=24&page=show_problem&problem=1239) problem using KMP algorithm. In [this](https://reponroy.wordpress.com/2015/04/29/kmp-minimum-length-of-a-repeated-string/) blog a technique is shown how failure function can be used to calculate minimum length repeated substring. The technique is as follows:

1. Compute prefix-suffix table `pi[ ]` for the given string.
2. Let `len` be the string length, and `last_in_pi` be the value stored at the last index of `pi` table.
3. Check whether `len % (len - last_in_pi) == 0` is true or not. If it is true then the length of the minimum length repeated substring is `(len - last_in_pi)`, otherwise it is the length of the given string.

I understand what is failure function and how it is used to find pattern in a text but I am struggling to understand proof of correctness of this technique.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question.

Comment: If this question is not appropriate for stack overflow, can you please suggest me where should i ask the question to get a good answer?

Comment: This is appropriate for SO, because it is asking how an algorithm works. This is a central point of the algorithm tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember that `Pi[i]` is defined as the (length of the) longest prefix of `your_string` that is a proper suffix (so not the whole string) of the substring `your_string[0 ... i]`.

There is an example on the blog post you linked to:

```
    0 1 2 3 4 5
S : a b a b a b
Pi: 0 0 1 2 3 4
```

Where we have:

> **a** b *a*
>
> **a b** *a b*

Etc. I hope this makes it clear what `Pi` (the prefix function / table) does.

Now, the blog says:

> The last value of prefix table = 4..
>   Now If it is a repeated string than , It’s minimal length would be 2. (6(string length) – 4) , Now

So you have to check if `len % (len - last_in_pi) == 0`. If yes, then `len - last_in_pi` is the length of the shortest repeated string (the period string).

This works because, if you rotate a string with `len(period)` positions either way, it will match itself. `len - last_in_pi` tells you how much you'd need to rotate.

Comment: **"So you have to check if len % (len - last_in_pi) == 0. If yes, then len - last_in_pi is the length of the shortest repeated string (the period string)."** But why does this work? I googled about the process and found it is known as Booth's Algorithm [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographically_minimal_string_rotation#Booth.27s_Algorithm)
@IVlad

Answer (score 1):

#### Problem

`S` (of length `Ls`) is the given string. `M` (of length `Lm`) is the largest proper suffix of `S`, which is also a prefix of `S`. We have to prove `Ls - Lm` is the length of the shortest period of `S`.

#### Proof by Contradiction

Let's say there were a period `Y` whose length `Ly < Ls - Lm` (i.e, it's shorter than the one the above technique gives).

An important property to note is that `M` is a proper prefix of `Y` or vice-versa depending on their lengths. We can denote this as `M = n*Y + Z`, where `n >= 0` and `Z` is the additional part and `Lz < Ly`. `Z` forms a prefix to `Y`, since `Y` repeats itself. Let `Y = Z + W`.

Consider `M` the suffix. Append the **previous** `Ly` number of characters from the original string S to it. This won't exceed the string length because (`Ly < Ls - Lm`). The new suffix is `(n + 1)*Y + Z`.

Consider `M` the prefix. Now append the **next** `Ly` number of characters from the original string S to it. The new prefix here is

```
M + (next Ly characters from S)
- > n*Y + Z + (Ly characters)  
- > n*Y + Z + (Ly - Lz characters) + (Lz characters)  
- > n*Y + (Z + W) + (Z)  
{The `Ly - Lz` characters should be `W` because `Z` and these together form `Y`; The last Lz characters are actually the the first Lz characters of Y which is nothing but Z}  

- > (n + 1)*Y + Z
```

Now we have a proper suffix of S which is also a prefix and is greater than `M`. But  we started off saying `M` is the longest proper suffix which is also a prefix. So it's a contradiction, implying such a `Y` can not exist.

Answer (score 0):

- Assume you have a string s of size n, which looks like s = x1x2x3...x[n-2]x[n-1]x[n]
- Assume s has a maximum common prefix/suffix of length len
- Then it's period is p = (n - len),  iff n % p == 0
- Induction：

  - Denote prefix = s[1...len], postfix = s[p+1...n]
  - Then we have prefix[1...p] == postfix[1...p] == s[p+1...2p]
  - Since s[p+1...2p] == prefix[p+1...2p] so postfix[1...p] == postfix[p+1...2p]
  - Recursively postfix[p+1...2p] == s[2p+1...3p] == prefix[2p+1...3p]
  - ...